# Red Hat AMQ broker errors in HA cluster configuration

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have Red Hat AMQ broker 7.4.1 HA cluster pair configured using shared storage over NFS with static discovery cluster.

Master's `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>100</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>250</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 62.5 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 16000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->

      <journal-buffer-timeout>16000</journal-buffer-timeout>

 


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>95</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>240000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>



      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->
      
      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <master>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </master>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>
      
      <connectors>
         <connector name="master-connector">tcp://server24:61616</connector>
        <connector name="slave-connector">tcp://server25:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <acceptors>

         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->

         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://server24:61616</acceptor>
         
      </acceptors>
        
        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="static-cluster">
                <connector-ref>master-connector</connector-ref>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>slave-connector</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>

         <address-setting match="Claim">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <max-delivery-attempts>-1</max-delivery-attempts>
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>



         <!--default for catch all-->
        <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

Slave's `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>
        

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>/Share/JBossMQ7.4/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>100</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>250</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 62.5 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 16000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>16000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>95</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>240000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->
      
      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <slave>
               <allow-failback>false</allow-failback>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </slave>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>
      
      <connectors>
         <connector name="master-connector">tcp://server24:61616</connector>
         <connector name="slave-connector">tcp://server25:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://server25:61616</acceptor>
      </acceptors>


        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="static-cluster">
                <connector-ref>slave-connector</connector-ref>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>master-connector</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>


         <address-setting match="Claim">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <max-delivery-attempts>-1</max-delivery-attempts>
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>


   
         <!--default for catch all-->
   
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>   

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>


      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

Although this is working but getting some errors/warnings regularly.
Normally we keep slave as live and master as backup. But after errors will start accumulating we will stop broker on slave and master will be live. Then we will again power up broker on slave and  stop on master. This will take us to starting state.
I have configured `<allow-failback>false</allow-failback>` since it was not able to failback effectively.

Errors before and after fail over:

```
2022-08-30 08:47:51,838 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /10.000.000.42:29260 within the 30,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-08-30 16:24:48,501 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: syscall:write(..) failed: Broken pipe [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2022-08-30 16:24:48,501 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: syscall:write(..) failed: Broken pipe [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2022-08-30 16:24:48,504 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: syscall:write(..) failed: Broken pipe [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2022-08-30 16:24:48,522 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /10.111.225.41:28018 within the 30,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
2022-08-30 16:24:48,535 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 Id=2 RUNNABLE
    at java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:241)
    at java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:213)


2022-08-30 16:24:48,541 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal] "Finalizer" daemon prio=8 Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@443d3450
    at java.base@11.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

2022-08-30 16:24:52,070 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222154: Error checking DLQ: ActiveMQShutdownException[errorType=SHUTDOWN_ERROR message=Journal must be in state=LOADED, was [STOPPED]]

2022-08-30 16:42:26,345 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] Errors occurred during the buffering operation : javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Consumer does not exist
```

Is there some issue with the configuration?

I am using NFSv3. Will it make impact?

Comment: The `AMQ212037` warnings imply network instability or potentially unstable client applications (e.g. crashing without closing their connection). The warnings from `org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal` look like part of a thread dump emitted by the critical analyzer before shutting down the broker. The `AMQ222154` warning indicates the broker is shutting down but applications are still trying to use it. I'd say the same about the `IllegalStateException`. It would help if you provided more of the log instead of just this little snippet.

Answer (score 0):

NFSv3 doesn't support the locking semantics required by ActiveMQ Artemis to be used as a shared storage device for high availability. You need to use NFSv4.

For what it's worth, the [NFSv4 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3530) was published 20 years ago. There's few (if any) reasons to still be using NFSv3.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. Point noted. But this setup has been working for last 2 years. The errors appear even when load is on one broker and not only the time of load switching. This is on client env and they have some bottleneck to upgrade to NFSv4. Please suggest if there is any tweak/optimization needed in broker settings or related configs to get rid of errors. For example we are planning to introduce GC parameter and ipv4 restriction.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me how HA can work as expected on NFSv3. That's the only configuration-specific problem I see. How would adding a GC parameter or IPv4 restriction help this situation?